# Can I create a checklist entry using org-capture?

Tags: org-mode, org-capture

It seems to me that org-capture requires templates to start with a heading (*). Can I not have a template like:

```
("d" "Daily Tasks" entry (file+datetree+prompt "daily.org")
     "- [ ] %?")
```

that does not start with a *.

Comment: Here is a link to a related thread, which contains an answer using `checkitem` instead of `entry`:  "*in org-mode, how to create checkbox items in org-capture?*":  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23351474/in-org-mode-how-to-create-checkbox-items-in-org-capture

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to change the third element the template ("entry type").  From the help:

```
type         The type of entry.  Valid types are:
               entry       an Org node, with a headline.  Will be filed
                           as the child of the target entry or as a
                           top-level entry.
               item        a plain list item, will be placed in the
                           first plain list at the target
                           location.
               checkitem   a checkbox item.  This differs from the
                           plain list item only is so far as it uses a
                           different default template.
               table-line  a new line in the first table at target location.
               plain       text to be inserted as it is.
```

For a checkbox you want `checkitem` instead of `entry`.